# Schauder basis and Eigenbases

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

There are several question in this site comparing different basis functions including Schauder basis and others, but I could not connect the difference between the Schauder basis and Eigenbasis clearly. Would someone please point the best way to contrast between the two?

Answer (score -1):

An eigenbasis is a basis consisting entirely of eigenvectors (vectors associated with a linear system of equations).

A Schauder basis is like a basis except they allow for infinite sums.

Comment: Thank you, Would you please relate Schauder basis to linear system to contrast them?